# Given a segment on a cone surface and a point on the cone surface find the closest point on the segment to the point.

Tags: geometry, surfaces

Points on the cone on a cone are defined by
$$
p=(\theta,z)
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle around the cone and $z$ is the distance along the axis.
I have a segment $S$ defined from $p_0$ to $p_1$ on the cone. To remove ambiguity the segment is defined as the shortest way across the cone. That is a segment can't wrap more that $\pi/2$ round the cone. ( Though extra points for solving the more general problem. There are an infinite number of *geodesics* between two points on a cone equivalent to spiral sections with decreasing pitch. )

The cone is defined as the surface of revolution around axis $z$ generated by the line
$$
r = gz + r_0
$$
where

- $r$ is the cone radius at position $z$ along the cone axis and
- $g$ is the slope of the cone
- $r_0$ is the radius of the cone at $z=0$
  Only the part of the cone up to the point where the line crosses zero is considered. ie: only the single cone not the dual cone.

So now given some point $p$ what is the closest point to $p$ on $S$.

Comment: Just unfold the cone, and find the projection of $p$ onto the segment.

Comment: I think I need to decide what I actually want. I forgot that a segment in $(\theta,z)$ is not the same as a segment unrolled. That is, between two points at the same $z$ and different $\theta$ the geodesic is *not* just a rotation in $\theta$ because unrolling the cone would generate an arc. My question is obviously not clear enough at the moment.

Comment: It is not true that "there are an infinite number of geodesics between two points on a cone". There is only one curve of minimal length, corresponding to a straight line on the unfolded surface.

Comment: A geodesic is not a "curve of minimal length" it is a "curve of local minimal length". On a cone there are often many *straight* lines between two points. For example here is a picture of multiple geodesics on a cone. http://www.rdrop.com/~half/Creations/Puzzles/cone.geodesics/cone.with.three.geodesics.png  from http://www.rdrop.com/~half/Creations/Puzzles/cone.geodesics/index.html but I think I'm at least wrong that there are infinite. For a cylinder there are infinite, mapping to tighter and tighter spirals.